# jdbc dymanic sql query with variable containg 's

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have asked this beacause i was not able to find the answer.

what i am doing is

```
 String selectTableSQL = "SELECT * FROM diseaseinfo WHERE diseaseName =""+diseaseName +'" AND name = '"+username+"'";
```

it is perfecty running unless and until diseases does not contain **'s** type of word like

> Wilms' tumor
>
> Addison's disease

etc....

so query like

```
SELECT * FROM diseaseinfo WHERE diseaseName = 'Adult Still's disease' AND name = 'add';
```

wont execute because of ' 's on `'Adult Still's`

and also in java i cant start string with `String selectTableSQL = ' ';` it will always be in `String selectTableSQL = " ";`

any solution?

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement`(s) and ***bind* variables**.

Comment: ok i will.Beside this any solution? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Write a correct string escape utility? [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql%28java.lang.String%29) (note that this is so non-trivial that the method has been removed from more recent versions of `StringEscapeUtils`).

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957497/dynamic-column-name-using-preparestatement-sql-query-with-variable-containg-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this case and any syntax error or SQL Injection you have to use PreparedStatement instead :

```
String selectTableSQL = "SELECT * FROM diseaseinfo WHERE col1 = ? and col2 = ?";
try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(selectTableSQL)) {

    ps.setString(1, value_1);
    ps.setString(2, value_2);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is `rs` in rs = ps.executeQuery();  there?

Comment: it is `ResultSet` to get results i already edit my answer @doe

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use queries in JDBC is to use `PreparedStatement` and bind variables.

But in your case, try replacing the single quotes `'` in your values with `\'`.

You can use a simple `diseaseName.replace("'", "\\'");` to do it.