# Dynamic column name using prepared statement + sql query with variable containing 's

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

My query

```
attributes.replace(" ' ", "");
//also used SET "+attributes+" 
String sql;
sql = "UPDATE diseaseinfo"
        + " SET ?=?"
        + "WHERE companyname = 'mycom' && diseaseName =?";

PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connects.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStmt.setString(1, attributes);
preparedStmt.setString(2, attrData);
preparedStmt.setString(3, medname);
System.out.println(preparedStmt);
```

it is giving me an error because query set the column name in string so it become like this on causes

```
 UPDATE diseaseinfo SET 'causes'='abc' WHERE companyname = 'mycom'  and diseaseName ='fever'
```

and through this question I get to know that I can't add dynamic column by prepared statement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136049/7794329

Now, the real question comes up: suppose if I will use a simple update query like in this question: [jdbc dymanic sql query with variable containg 's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941818/jdbc-dymanic-sql-query-with-variable-containg-s?noredirect=1#comment74916477_43941818)

It says you can't enter value with 's in your simple sql query because it will again make the query syntactical error for example :

```
SELECT * FROM diseaseinfo WHERE diseaseName = 'Adult Still's disease' AND name = 'add';
```

Here it wont execute because of ' 's on 'Adult Still's

Then it won't work with simple query. What should I do now? What to use? To set dynamic column with taking care of 's in the query.

I am not worried about SQL injection because i am working on local. And I just want my query to be executed.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection. Also it will escape special character

Comment: `Also it will escape special character`  that is exactly in my question.. i think u didnt get the ques

Comment: Since you want your field to update to be dynamic don't use prepared statement on it just do: `"UPDATE diseaseinfo SET" +aVarWithTheFieldName+ "=?"`and pass the actual parameters as PS as you are already doing.

Comment: i already tried it... it is again giving me 'causes' <- this so it is not executing @JorgeCampos

Comment: i agree with @JorgeCampos why you use `'` in the name of your columns doe?

Comment: The `aVarWithTheFieldName` should not be given with a prepared statement which will identify it as string and add the quotes. You need your code to take care of it. If you already tried it, it means that what ever the value of `'causes'` is coming from it already have the quotes

Comment: i am not using it is making qurey like this only `UPDATE diseaseinfo SET 'causes'='abc' WHERE companyname = 'mycom'  and diseaseName ='fever' ` @YCF_L

Comment: in this case you can use `"UPDATE diseaseinfo SET" + aVarWithTheFieldName.replace("'", "") + "=?"` note the `replace("'", "")` just from the name of your column

Comment: updating the ques

Comment: so it will gives you `UPDATE diseaseinfo SET causes='abc' WHERE companyname = 'mycom' and diseaseName ='fever'`which is a valid query

Comment: you ca edit your answer @doe dont post your code in comment

Comment: I'm not a java developer - But I'm pretty sure that `setString()` adds the single quotes to your query.

Comment: don't use replace with spaces `attributes.replace(" ' ", "");` !! use this `attributes.replace("'", "");` instead

Comment: @YCF_L well `UPDATE diseaseinfo SET" + aVarWithTheFieldName.replace("'", "")` this works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right. We can't supply identifiers as bind parameters. The name of the column has to be part of the SQL text.

We can dynamically incorporate the name of the column into the SQL text with something like this:

```
  sql = "UPDATE diseaseinfo"
      + " SET `" + colname + "` = ?"
      + " WHERE companyname = 'mycom' AND diseaseName = ?";
```

And supply values for the two remaining bind parameters

```
  preparedStmt.setString(1, attrData);
  preparedStmt.setString(2, medname);
```

And you are absolutely correct about being concerned about SQL Injection.

Supplied as bind values, single quotes in the values of `attrData` and `medname` won't be an issue, in terms of SQL Injection.

But the example I've provided *is* vulnerable through incorporating the  `colname` variable into the SQL text, if we don't have some guaranteed that `colname` is "safe" to include in the statement.

So we need to make the assignment of a value to `colname` "safe".

Several approaches we can use do that. The most secure would be a "whitelist" approach.  The code can ensure that only specific allowed "safe" values get assigned to `colname`, before `colname` gets included into the SQL text.

As a simple example:

```
  String colname;
  if (attributes.equals("someexpectedvalue") {
      colname = "columnname_to_be_used";
  } else if (attributes.equals("someothervalid") {
      colname = "valid_columname";
  } else {
     // unexpected/unsupported attributes value so
     // handle condition or throw an exception 
  }
```

A more flexible approach is to ensure that a backtick character doesn't appear in `colname`.  In the example, the value of `colname` is being *escaped* by enclosing it in backticks. So, as long as a backtick character doesn't appear in `colname`, we will prevent a supplied value from being interpreted as anything other than as an identifier.

For a more generic (and complicated) approach to using hardcoded backtick characters, we could consider making use the `supportsQuotedIdentifiers` and `getIdentifierQuoteString` methods of `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` class.

---

(In the OP code, we don't see the datatype of contents of `attributes`.  We see a call to a method named `replace`, and the arguments that are supplied to that. Assuming that `attributes` is a String, and that's supposed to be a column name,  it's not at all clear why we would have "space single quote space" in the string, or why we need to remove that. Other than this mention, this answer doesn't address that.)